# Main function not executing my second function

Tags: java, eclipse, function, selenium, automation

I have made two functions and I have called them in main. When I execute the program it only runs the first function in the main after that program stops .     if i paste the second function in main above the first one it only runs the function that is defined first but does not runs the second function.

```java
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Testing {
    public static void login_and_widthdrawl() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/ctp-016/Downloads/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://staging.cintech.com/login");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
        email.sendKeys("zahid12@mailinator.com");

        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        password.sendKeys("zahid12@");

        WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("login"));
        textbox.click();

        // checking widthdrawl functionality from here 
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("navbarDropdown")).click();
        driver
            .findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-header-guest/section[1]/nav/div/div/ul/li[3]/div/a[2]"))
            .click();

        // SELECTING BTC CRYPTO AND ENTRING VALUES FROM  HERE 

        //  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        //  WebElement ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-withdrawal/section/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span")));
        //   ele.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        WebElement submit1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select2\"]"));
        submit1.click();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement submit12 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/span/span/span[2]/ul/li[2]"));
        submit12.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        WebElement volume =
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/div[1]/input"));
        volume.sendKeys("0.001");

        WebElement wallet = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
            "/html/body/app-root/div/app-withdrawal/section/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/input"));
        wallet.sendKeys("1asas");

        WebElement click = driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-withdrawal/section/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/button"));
        click.click();

        //   WebElement secret2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"VerifyTwoFA\"]/div/div/div/app-verify-twofactor/div/div/form/div[1]/input"));
        //    secret2.sendKeys("0");

        WebElement submit2 = driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton"));
        submit2.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
        //driver.quit();

        // clear the fields 

        WebElement volumeclear =
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/div[1]/input"));
        volumeclear.clear();


        WebElement walletclear =
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/input"));
        walletclear.clear();
    }


    public static void ether() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/ctp-016/Downloads/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //     driver = null;
        driver.get("http://staging.cintech.com/login");

        //       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //       Thread.sleep(2000);

        //  WebElement selected_value_from_combo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select2-mySelect2-result-2d1f-3\"]"));
        //  selected_value_from_combo .click();
        //        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        WebElement eth_volume =
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/div[1]/input"));
        eth_volume.sendKeys("1");

        WebElement eth_wallet =
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/input"));
        eth_wallet.sendKeys("1asas");


        WebElement click_widthdrawl = driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-withdrawal/section/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/button"));
        click_widthdrawl.click();

        //     WebElement secret_eth = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"VerifyTwoFA\"]/div/div/div/app-verify-twofactor/div/div/form/div[1]/input"));
        //     secret_eth.sendKeys("0");

        WebElement submit_eth = driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//*[@id=\"VerifyTwoFA\"]/div/div/div/app-verify-twofactor/div/div/form/div[2]/button"));
        submit_eth.click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        Alert alert_eth = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert_eth.accept();

        // clear the fields 

        WebElement ethvolumeclear =
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/div[1]/input"));
        ethvolumeclear.clear();


        WebElement ethwalletclear =
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/input"));
        ethwalletclear.clear();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ether();
        login_and_widthdrawl();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your functions throwing `InterruptedException` by any chance? I see your `main` throws it up. Maybe wrap those two functions in main into two try/catch blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure why it s happening, try this to know actual problem:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        try{
             ether();
        login_and_widthdrawl();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes thank so much . it was unable to find a element after commenting that both functon run perfectly